# Open contact record in a new tab from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have created a visualforce page that displays a list of contacts associated with an opportunity. This is displayed in a section on the opportunity page layout. I need to open the contact record in a new tab.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
extensions="OpportunityApprenticeDetails_CX" tabStyle="Contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listContacts}" var="conts">

        <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
            <apex:commandLink value="{!conts.firstname}" target="_blank">
            <apex:param name="param1" value="{!conts.id}" assignTo="
            {!contact.id}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="LastName">
            <apex:outputField value="{!conts.lastname}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!conts.email}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!conts.accountid}">
            {!conts.account.name}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>


    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this way using `apex:outputLink` and in the value attribute specify `URLFOR` with the action and Id.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, conts.id)}" target="_blank">
        {!conts.firstname}
 </apex:outputLink>
```

Refer my blog post [Different ways of navigation](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/different-ways-of-navigation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target=` attribute on your [`<apex:outputLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) components to control how links are opened. Using [`target="_blank"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) will result in opening a new window or tab.

In this instance, you may be having difficulty because you're using an `<apex:commandLink>` instead of an `<apex:outputLink>`. What you're doing is not firing a controller action method, so you don't need a command link and a parameter. You can populate the URL of your output link component using the `URLFOR()` formula function, or simply construct it with a forward slash as you do already in the Account link lower in your page. (I like to use `URLFOR()` because it protects against implementation details, although that one seems unlikely to change).